# How to build a XPath with concat() and position() in a xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to show the following xml data as a table, each point in a row with some of its values as columns. Each point has many more values than the three in the example, but they all have the same number of values and I want to select some of them. In addition, there are several other elements with names other than 'Point[x]' including an element named 'Count' that indicates the number of points.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report.xsl" ?>
<root>
  <body>
    <part>
        <values>
          <item name="Foo" value="123" unit="" />
          <item name="Baa" value="abc" unit="" />
          <item name="Count" value="3" unit="" />
          <item name="Point[1].Value1" value="640" unit="m³" />
          <item name="Point[1].Value2" value="20" unit="°C" />
          <item name="Point[1].Value3" value="40" unit="%" />
          <item name="Point[1].Value4" value="0" unit="" />
          <item name="Point[2].Value1" value="641" unit="m³" />
          <item name="Point[2].Value2" value="21" unit="°C" />
          <item name="Point[2].Value3" value="41" unit="%" />
          <item name="Point[2].Value4" value="0" unit="" />
          <item name="Point[3].Value1" value="642" unit="m³" />
          <item name="Point[3].Value2" value="22" unit="°C" />
          <item name="Point[3].Value3" value="42" unit="%" />
          <item name="Point[3].Value4" value="0" unit="" />
        </values>
    </part>
  </body>
</root>
```

This is what I want to get:

```
No   Value1 [m³]   Value2 [°C]   Value3 [%]
1    640           20            40
2    641           21            41
3    642           22            42
```

And this is what I get with the stylesheet below:

```
No   Value1 [m³]   Value2 [°C]   Value3 [%]   Col1              Col2              Col3
1    640           20            40           Point[1].Value1   Point[1].Value2   123
2    641           20            40           Point[2].Value1   Point[2].Value2   123
3    642           20            40           Point[3].Value1   Point[3].Value2   123
```

I loop over all matches of "].Value1" and try to build the other XPaths with concat() and position(). As you can see in Col2 concat() works as expected. However, Col3 shows that my `select` expression isn't working.

So what's the correct expression to select the correct point in each row?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Value1 [m³]</th>
                <th>Value2 [°C]</th>
                <th>Value3 [%]</th>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(@name, '].Value1')]">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//item[@name='Point[1].Value2']/@value"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//item[@name='Point[1].Value3']/@value"/>
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Point[', position(), '].Value2')"/>
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//item[concat(@name='Point[', position(), '].Value2')]/@value"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit: described the structure of the data in more detail

Comment: If you know three adjacent `item` elements form a row I would use positional grouping, so in XSLT 2 `for-each-group select="item" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 3"` and `current-group()` to populate the columns, in XSLT 1 probably `for-each select="item[position() mod 3 = 1]"`, then inside you can access process `. | following-sibling::item[position() &lt; 3]` to populate your columns.

Comment: 1st: I edited the first paragraph of my question to describe the data structure in more detail.
2nd: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: You haven't said which version of XSLT you are using. This is a grouping problem, so solutions using XSLT 2..0+ are going to be much simpler than solutions using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Value1 [m³]</th>
                            <th>Value2 [°C]</th>
                            <th>Value3 [%]</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="root/body/part/values/item[(position() mod 3) = 1]">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::item[1]/@value"/>
                                </td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::item[2]/@value"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comment of Martin Honnen I found a solution:

```
            <xsl:for-each select="//item[position() mod 4 = 0 and contains(@name, 'Point')]">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@value, '0.00')"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[contains(@name, 'Value2')]/@value"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[contains(@name, 'Value3')]/@value"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the solutions submitted so far seem to assume that the number of values for each point is statically known, which seems to contradict the stated requirement.

With XSLT 2.0+ it's easy enough to generalize the solution:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="item[starts-with(@ame, 'Point[')]"
                    group-adjacent="substring-before(@name, '.')"/>
  <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="position(), current-group()">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```